# Suppose $B$ is a set and $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of sets. Then if $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B$, then $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I have a problem with a statement in my proof which I think might be incomplete or incorrect.

Here is my proof:

*Proof.* Suppose $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B$ and suppose $x \in \mathcal{F}$. Suppose $y \in x$. Then since $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B$, $x \subseteq B$. But $y \in x$, so $y \in B$. Since $y$ is arbitrary so one can conclude that $x \in \mathscr{P}(B)$. But then $x$ is arbitrary, hence one can conclude that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$. Therefore $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$.
QED

The problem I have is the statement ``Then since $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B$, $x \subseteq B$.'' Since the union of $\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of $B$, every element in $\mathcal{F}$ must also be a subset of $B$ since the union contains all the elements of every member of $\mathcal{F}$. However, do I need some other statement to reach such conclusion, or is the statement entirely incorrect?

Comment: Looks right to me! If you feel the original proof isn't clear enough, you could add your sentence "Since the union ... of every member of $\mathcal{F}$" as further justification.

Comment: A look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3303681/75923) and its answer might help.

Comment: $y$ serves no useful purpose in this. You already state $x \subseteq B$. That is the very definition of $x \in \mathscr P(B)$. I think I would just go with "$\forall x \in \mathcal F, x\subseteq \bigcup \mathcal F \subseteq B$ so $x \in \mathscr P(B)$. Ergo, $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathscr P(B)$."

Comment: Looking at some of your other comments, it seems your uncertainty is about whether you can just claim $\forall x \in \mathcal F, x \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal F$. But that follows immediately from the definition of $$\bigcup \mathcal F := \{y \mid \exists x, y \in x \text{ and }x \in \mathcal F\}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that as you pointed out that statement is incorrect.
However if you substitute it with

"$y\in x\in \mathcal{F}\rightarrow y\in\bigcup\mathcal{F}, \quad y\in\bigcup\mathcal{F}\subset B\rightarrow y\in B $"

it should all work

Comment: In this case, the intermediate step $x \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{F}$ cannot be left out? As the last comment in the post pointed out, this is the step which I skipped before concluding that $x \subseteq B$. The logic is since $x \in \mathcal{F}$, all the members of $x$ must be contained within $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$. Hence, $x \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{F}$. And with this step, I can invoke $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B$ to conclude that $x \subseteq B$.

Comment: I want my proof to be as concise as possible, but I don't know whether I can leave out the mentioned step or not.